# Scala: Add value at the end of each row except the last row in a file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I'm new to scala. Have a scenario where we need to add value at the end of each row except the last row in a file. Have a written a code in python and its working. I'm trying to implement the same in scala without success. Please help.

```
def create_ddl():
    with open('C:\\Downloads\\output.csv', 'r') as istr:
            lines = istr.readlines()
            last = lines[-1]

            create='CREATE TABLE '+table_name+ ' ( '
            reformat="ROW FORMAT DELIMITED \n FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\\t’ \n LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\\n’;"
            with open('C:\\Downloads\\final_output_success.csv', 'w') as ostr:
                    print(create, file=ostr)
                    for line in lines:
                            if line is last:
                                    print(line, file=ostr)
                            else:
                                    line = line.rstrip('\n') + ','
                                    print(line, file=ostr)
                    print(')', file=ostr)
                    print(reformat, file=ostr)
```

Comment: Do you have any Scala code to paste? Doesn't matter if it's not working just easier for others to help if you show where you got to.

Comment: The snippet looks like Python.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov he is asking how to rewrite this Python to Scala...

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok ah, indeed. I've missed that point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get the column names from a file and append comma between them to get the "create table" syntax. You can do this with mkString function.

Here is my content in windows temp dir.

```
C:\Users\winos>type temp\cols.txt
col1
col2
col3
col4

C:\Users\winos>
C:\Users\winos>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x = scala.io.Source.fromFile("temp\\cols.txt").getLines
x: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> x.mkString(",")
res0: String = col1,col2,col3,col4

scala>
```

If you have the data in an array, it works in the same way

```
scala> val arr = Array("cola","colb","colc")
arr: Array[String] = Array(cola, colb, colc)

scala> arr.mkString("|")
res4: String = cola|colb|colc

scala>
```